# Selenium (Java): the method dndScript() is undefined

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to verify that a former colleague's old demo Selenium script still works, but have run into a curious error.  The colleague is no longer around to consult, unfortunately.  First, here's the script in question, which is supposed to drag and drop one element over another on a page:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DragNDrop {
    
    @Test
    public void testDragAndDropWithCheck() throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\WebDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");

        By css = By.cssSelector("div[id^=\"column-\"]");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        
        Supplier<List<WebElement>> fetchComponents = () -> wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(css));
        /**
         * Starting check for element position
         */
        List<WebElement> startingCheck = fetchComponents.get();

        Assert.assertEquals("Starting - Draggable number does not match!", 2, startingCheck.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("Starting - A position does not match!", "A", startingCheck.get(0).getText());
        Assert.assertEquals("Starting - B position does not match!", "B", startingCheck.get(1).getText());

        int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(startingCheck.size());
        WebElement from = startingCheck.get(index);
        WebElement to = startingCheck.get(1 - index);

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        jse.executeScript(
            dndScript() + "simulateDragAndDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1])",
            from,
            to);
        /**
         * Ending check for element position
         */
        List<WebElement> endingCheck = fetchComponents.get();

        Assert.assertEquals("Ending - Draggable number does not match!", 2, endingCheck.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("Ending - A position does not match!", "A", endingCheck.get(1).getText());
        Assert.assertEquals("Ending - B position does not match!", "B", endingCheck.get(0).getText());
    }

}
```

The problem is with this part:

```
jse.executeScript(
    dndScript() + "simulateDragAndDrop(arguments[0], arguments[1])",
    from,
    to);
```

Eclipse highlighted dndScript() and threw the message:

> The method dndScript() is undefined for the type DragNDrop

I first figured this was due to a missing import, so I got to googling, but I can't find any information on it.  The most I could find was some references to something called "RichFaces", but I couldn't find any further clarification (may be my own fault -- I'm by no means a Selenium/Java expert).

Any idea on what the story is with this function and how to properly implement it in this script?

Comment: You need a string there.  Just create your "dndScript" as a string variable and pass that in instead of the method which does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely related to the missing import (probably the static one). Since this is just a method name there could be three cases:

1. This is a static method in scope of some different classand used to be imported with static import
2. This is the method that has to be implemented in the scope of your current class
3. This is the method that has to be implemented in scope of parent classes

The reason of you currently have is that the code of your current class changed since that time. You need to check revision history if you take this code from version control.

There are few possible stories which seem possible:

- There was a method in scope of current class and then it was moved so some parent class. In some reason someone forgot to add `extends` keyword to current class.
- There was a method in scope of parent class. After that someone decided to break relationship between the classes and forgot to move that method to your current class.
- There was static method in some different class. It was imported to the current class as `static import`. Then someone loaded that class to IDE and didn't add that "different class" to project's class path. Then they applied "organize imports" feature which removed that broken import from your current class.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation!  Unfortunately this was a snippet of code shared on a blog post, with no full source code provided.  I'm the tech writer asked to update the post and verify the code sample is still valid, but since this is all I was left to work with, it seems I'm a bit out of luck.